# Wrong bytes from UTF-16 encoding

Tags: java, unicode, utf-16

I have a character '' Unicode value is **U+1F62D** binary equivalent is **11111011000101101** . Now I want to convert this character to byte array . My steps

1) As binary representation is bigger than 2 bytes I use 4 bytes

**XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX1 11110110 00101101**

2) Now I replace all 'X' with '0'

**00000000 00000001 11110110 00101101**

3) Decimal equivalents

**00000000(0) 00000001(1) 11110110(-10) 00101101(45)**

This is my code

```
@Test
    public void testUtf16With4Bytes() throws Exception {
        assertThat(
                new String(
                        new byte[]{0,1,-10,45},
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE
                ),
                is("")
        );
    }
```

This is the output

```
ava.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is ""
     but: was ""
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: The first byte is wrong. It shouldn't be 0x0 but 0xD8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You miss that some UTF characters are stored as [surrogate pairs](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html#utf-16-surrogate-pairs):

> In UTF-16, characters in ranges U+0000—U+D7FF and U+E000—U+FFFD are stored as a single 16 bits unit. Non-BMP characters (range U+10000—U+10FFFF) are stored as “surrogate pairs”, two 16 bits units: an high surrogate (in range U+D800—U+DBFF) followed by a low surrogate (in range U+DC00—U+DFFF). A lone surrogate character is invalid in UTF-16, surrogate characters are always written as pairs (high followed by low).

character is `U+1F62D` so it falls into `U+10000—U+10FFFF` range. It's represented with a surrogate pair `U+D83D` `U+DE2D`, as `byte[]` it would be `[-40, 61, -34, 45]`.